# What do <header> and <footer> actually do?

Tags: html, web-applications, user-interface, semantic-markup

What's the point of header and footer?

Given that they are rendered on the page in the order they are written, as demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BanksySan/BmVeU/1/) what is the difference between them?

```
<article>
    <footer>This is a footer</footer>
    <header>This is a header</header>
</article>
```

Comment: Semantics. That's it really. HTML is a *markup* language after all. The tags you choose to use give extra information as to the meaning of the document.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Then what were they made for?  To me, `<footer>`, `<header>` and `<aside>` are semantically the same, just in different bits of the page.  They are all 'asides'.

Comment: The spec is the best place to look for that information. For example, have a look at the section for [the `header` element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-header-element), which explains that it "represents a group of introductory or navigational aids".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only definite source is the HTML5 spec. It defines the meaning of these elements.

For the [`header` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element):

> The `header` element represents a group of introductory or navigational aids.

For the [`footer` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-footer-element):

> The `footer` element represents a footer for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element. A footer typically contains information about its section such as who wrote it, links to related documents, copyright data, and the like.

Both sections give further comments and examples for the intended use.

In my own words:

`footer` is a place for metadata, like author name, publication date, categories/tags etc.. Each sectioning element (`section`, `article`, `aside`, `nav`) can have its own `footer` element(s). If the `footer` is not part of such a sectioning element, it applies to the whole page. Example:

```
<body>
  <article>
    <footer><!-- metadata about the article --></footer>
  </article>
  <footer><!-- metadata about the whole page --></footer>
</body>
```

The `header` element is for introductory content, like headings, summary/abstract, warnings like "NSFW" etc.

Note that the HTML5 spec doesn’t contain the same wording about sectioning elements for the `header` like it is the case for `footer`. However, this is already [fixed in HTML5.1](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2013Mar/0066.html) (see the [relevant bug](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=20550)) and will probably be changed in HTML5, too.

You shouldn’t pay attention to the naming of these elements. A `header` could also appear at the end and a `footer` at the beginning of an article.

The overall picture: `header` and `footer` (and `address`) are useful to mark-up the content of a sectioning element (or the whole page) that is **not** part of the main content of the sectioning element (or the whole page).

A simple example without `footer`:

```
<article>
  <h1>About me</h1>

    <h2>What I love</h2>
      <p>I like <cite>The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy</cite>.</p>

    <h2>What I hate</h2>
      <p>I hate <cite>Pacman</cite>.</p>

    <p>Tags: <a href="/personal">personal</a>, <a href="/fandom">fandom</a></p>

</article>
```

↑ Here the last paragraph (containing the tags for this article) would be in scope of the heading "What I hate". This is of course wrong, as I don’t hate "Tags", "personal", or "fandom". So we should reflect this within the markup, so that this paragraph is not associated with the previous heading:

```
<article>
  <h1>About me</h1>

    <h2>What I love</h2>
      <p>I like <cite>The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy</cite>.</p>

    <h2>What I hate</h2>
      <p>I hate <cite>Pacman</cite>.</p>

    <footer>
      <p>Tags: <a href="/personal">personal</a>, <a href="/fandom">fandom</a></p>
    </footer>
</article>
```

↑ Now that we put the tags in `footer`, they are no longer in scope of "What I hate". Instead, they now represent the footer (→ the metadata) for the whole `article` element.

Comment: Would it be fair to say the `header` and `footer` are bad names, as they infer a position on the page, rather than it's context or purpose?

Comment: @BanksySan: It’s a problem with almost all element names. `article` is not only for articles; `ol` is not for every *ordered* list; etc. I guess in the case of `header`/`footer` it’s what is true for the 80%, so to say: if a web author didn’t read about the definition of these elements and uses them according to the traditional understanding of header and footer, the author will probably do it right intentionally, in most cases at least. Or in other words: the definition of `header`/`footer` is a superset of the traditional header/footer understanding, not in all but in many cases.

Comment: @BanksySan: Historically, it is said that the ideas for these new HTML5 elements came from analysing most used `class` names on `div`. After adding them to the spec, their definitions mature over the time (when trying to formalize the meaning of them). That could be an explanation why it’s not a 100% match of the traditional understanding of header/footer (it’s presentational in many cases, so that’s no good fit for HTML anyway).

Answer (score 0):

In general in a  tag the header can contain the subject of the article and the footer  the author and/or time written.

You should read the following links for further explanation

[header element](http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/)

[footer element](http://html5doctor.com/the-footer-element-update/)

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp , semantic tags are used to "clearly define different parts of a web site". they are just to tell the browser and maybe others where something is.
its an alternative to `<div id="header">` for example

i hope i could help